# Pandas - GroupBy values based on first letter in the column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a column in a dataframe containing a sample of the following values:

```
     Cabin
0    A12
1    C27
2    D56
3    E87
4    G21
5    J64
```

I would like to create another column containing ONLY the first letter of that column:

```
     Cabin   New_Cabin
0    A12     A
1    C27     C
2    D56     D
3    E87     E
4    G21     G
5    J64     J
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here it is, young `Pandas` apprentice.

`df['my_easy_column'] = df.mycol.str[0]`

Comment: or `df.mycol.str[0]` aswell